# DLL set path before loading dependencies

Tags: gcc, dll, path

I'd like to find a working solution to my problem, that is "altering process PATH variable before loading DLL dependencies".

Before explaining it in details, I'd like to summarize some requirements that cannot be modified. I've found some solutions in other posts here, but no-one satisfies them:

- I'm using MinGW GCC, and no other toolchains are allowed (even MS VS).
- Altering system (or user) PATH variable using computer settings is NOT an option, and the path where the main DLL is copied is not a system path.
- It's not possible (of course) to use the main DLL in the same path of the application that loads it (otherwise this post would have been a nonsense).
- Cannot load the dependent DLL with LoadLibrary.

So, I've created a DLL, called main.dll, that depends on A.dll, that is in the same directory of main.dll, but different from executable one.

I'd like to execute GetModuleFileName and SetEnvironmentVariable in DllMain or whatever other place just before A.dll gets loaded, so I can fix the PATH variable only for the running process.

The only way that I found to solve this problem was to create a simple new main.dll, that publishes the same methods of the original main.dll, change path at DllMain, and then, at first call of one of the methods, performs a LoadLibrary. The main issue is that I have different versions of main.dll, with different public methods, and I've to create a new "bridge" anytime I create a new main.dll, and that's very annoying (and can also have bugs).

I read about delayed loading, but I haven't found yet a way that I can use with MinGW.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!!!